# Bluemix, push application with server.xml vs whole Liberty Server, is there performance difference?

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have a multiple options to push my application to [Bluemix](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/), single `WAR` or `EAR` file, `WAR` file with `server.xml` file if I need some customization in settings or even push whole **Websphere Liberty Server**. 
When do I need to use the last option and what its impact on a performance in comparison with other options?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general there is no impact on performance; depending on what you are doing you may result in exactly the same runtime configuration (and thus performance).

The most noticeable difference will come from tuning server.xml: Instead of letting the buildpack choose the runtime configuration (and the "features" that will be running), you can trim down features to a minimum (removing everything you may not be using, including logging for example) or add more capabilities (https, jax-rs, ...).

Pushing an entire server is normally necessary if your customizations just do not fit in just server.xml changes. You may be adding libraries (jar files, e.g. database drivers) that are not part of the buildpack-offered runtime. Again, this may or may not come with a performance cost; it just depend on what changes you are doing.

For for information, see the default server.xml and some possible customizations [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/blob/master/docs/server-xml-options.md). You can also read [an example of adding drivers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_my_sql_manually.html) to a buildpack server, MySQL in this case -- this is not specific to Bluemix, but rather a Liberty runtime configuration that you can *also* apply to Bluemix by pushing a server directory.

Comment: Do you know if there is any implication regarding the cost of the `cf push` command itself?

Comment: Do you mean if 'cf' tool API commands are charged, to credit card? In that case - no. Only services and apps have associated costs -- and of course if by pushing an app you are creating a new app/service, or starting an app that was otherwise stopped, this may incur in costs.

Comment: :-) Was referring to "cost" in terms of upload time, sorry. Is it a much bigger upload than just an app ulpoad?

Comment: Ah :) No, in terms of upload, it is mostly bound to the app upload. You can see which file(s) it uploads while you run it. In fact, in many cases if you are just changing config (e.g. manifest.yml), most of the upload will be cached by cf or by bluemix so the upload is indeed very small.