# Using multiple websphere liberty profile servers instead of a single websphere 8?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-liberty, ibmhttpserver

In following my previous question [Bluemix, push application with server.xml vs whole Liberty Server, is there performance difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431594/bluemix-push-application-with-server-xml-vs-whole-liberty-server-is-there-perf) I'd thought is it possible to replace single [Websphere Application Server 8](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1106_alcott/1106_alcott.html) with multiple applications, by multiple [Websphere Liberty Profile server 8.5](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/websphere-liberty/), where every Websphere Liberty Profile Server will host a single application.

I'm concerned regarding this statement [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/websphere-liberty/)

> yet ready for production

But from other side I understand that [Bluemix](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#liberty) already use it in production.

So, my questions are:

1. Can I use Websphere Liberty Profile in production environment?
2. Is there any performance decrease when multiple Websphere Liberty Profile servers running on a single machine with [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) or [IBM HTTP server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_HTTP_Server) as a forward proxy?

Related questions:

1. [Difference between ibm web sphere liberty profile and ibm web sphere liberty core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857223/difference-between-ibm-web-sphere-liberty-profile-and-ibm-web-sphere-liberty-cor/30858042#30858042)

Comment: I updated the page on WASdev to read and ready for production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1. Can I use Websphere Liberty Profile in production environment?***

Yes, you can use Liberty Profile in production, see the following [WebSphere Application Server family](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/was-overview):

> All production editions come with entitlement to use the WebSphere
>   Liberty Profile—a simplified, lightweight, dynamic runtime suitable
>   for development **and production** which allows configuration and
>   application updates without restarting the server runtime

For small scale deployments (max 2GB Heap for all instances in organization) you can use it for free in production. For details check [What the Liberty runtime license lets you do](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/websphere-application-server-everyone/).

***2. Is there any performance decrease when multiple WebSphere Liberty Profile servers running on a single machine with Nginx or IBM HTTP server as a forward proxy?***

This depends on your applications, so there is no way to tell that without testing. You will be running two JVMs instead of one, so if one JVM was utilizing your all resources, then 2 JVMs  will compete for same amount of resources and may see performance decrease.

So in summary you have to test, as it depends on applications and hardware resources.